# LiveData.addSource onChanged event not calling Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture

I am working with Android Archi+Retrofit+RxAndroid in Kotlin. I need to update my Data object when get response from server. But livedata.addSource's onChanged is not calling.

I am taking help from Git code:- https://github.com/shahbazahmed1269/AndroidGithubIssues

Here is my code in Kotlin:-

```
class LoginRepository : BaseRepository() {

fun callLoginApi(data: HashMap<String, String>): LiveData<LoginResponse> {

    val liveData: MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> = MutableLiveData<LoginResponse>()

//        val call = mApiService.getLoginUser(data)

    mApiService.getLoginUser(data)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    { user ->
                        liveData.value = user
                        Log.e("response", user.toString())
                    },
                    { error ->
                        liveData.value = LoginResponse(error = error.localizedMessage)
                        Log.e("Error", error.message)

                    })
    return liveData
}
}


open class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
lateinit var loginResponse : MediatorLiveData<LoginResponse>
lateinit var loginRepo:LoginRepository;
init {
    loginResponse = MediatorLiveData<LoginResponse>()
    loginRepo = LoginRepository()
}

fun callLoginApi(data: HashMap<String, String>) {
//        val loginResponse  = MediatorLiveData<LoginResponse>()

    loginResponse.addSource(
            loginRepo.callLoginApi(data),
            { loginResponse -> Log.e("Response  model",loginResponse.toString()) }
    )
}
```

}

My Response from LoginRepository is printing but not from ViewModel class.

Comment: Are you attaching a lifecycle owner to your `loginResponse`?  Can you show the code from you `activity/fragment` that invokes this call from your viewmodel?

Comment: I am not using lifecycleOwner.

Comment: I am calling  mViewModel.callLoginApi(hash) from Activity. where hash is HashMap of data

Comment: Are you observing the loginResponse in your LifecycleOwner class?

Comment: @AmmY you need to observe `loginResponse` to  trigger it.  Live data requires a lifecycle owner which I'm assuming in your case will be your activity.

Comment: @Naveed I didn't implement observe in my lifecycleOwner class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the official docs for `addSource()` method [MediatorLiveData reference docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData#addSource(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CS%3E,%20androidx.lifecycle.Observer%3C?%20super%20S%3E)), its written

> onChanged callback will be called only when this MediatorLiveData is active.

Please make sure that you are observing the `loginResponse` `LiveData` in your LifecycleOwner class appropriately.

Comment: Can this be observed inside the ViewModel?